# Rails 2.3 - What is the hot auto-complete plugin / gem right now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I need to add multiple autocomplete "fields" to my web-app, I'm looking at both the auto-complete and simple_auto_complete gems, both look like they will do what I need.

Has anyone looked at either of these in depth or had experience with them - any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To Answer my Own Question, I went for the simple_auto_complete gem because it looks more flexible & I can use it with JQuery, auto-complete requires script.aculo.us which I'm not a huge fan of. Hope this helps someone.